# Can`t compile project

Tags: rust

I have some problems probably due to incorrect cargo or rust settings.

I using MinGW on windows and probably must set a CC or something like that or modify env variables.

I thought that maybe an error will be solved when I change the framework, but it did not help.

Here is the output of the console with an error:

```
C:\Users\user0\Desktop\app>cargo run 
   Compiling minimp3-sys v0.3.2     
   Compiling bzip2-sys v0.1.11+1.0.8
   Compiling miniz_oxide v0.4.4
   Compiling quote v1.0.19
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: cc1.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in

error: failed to run custom build command for `minimp3-sys v0.3.2`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\user0\Desktop\app\target\debug\build\minimp3-sys-6587a736db4ed872\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
  --- stdout
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-gnu")
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-gnu")
  CC_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu = None
  CC_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu = None
  HOST_CC = None
  CC = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu = None
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  CFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("true")
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  running: "gcc.exe" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "minimp3/" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-DMINIMP3_IMPLEMENTATION" "-o" "C:\\Users\\user0\\Desktop\\app\\target\\debug\\build\\minimp3-sys-2cb72c58d710f12a\\out\\minimp3.o" "-c" "minimp3.c"
  cargo:warning=cc1.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
  exit code: 1

  --- stderr


  error occurred: Command "gcc.exe" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "minimp3/" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-DMINIMP3_IMPLEMENTATION" "-o" "C:\\Users\\user0\\Desktop\\app\\target\\debug\\build\\minimp3-sys-2cb72c58d710f12a\\out\\minimp3.o" "-c" "minimp3.c" with args "gcc.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 1).


warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: cc1.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in

error: failed to run custom build command for `bzip2-sys v0.1.11+1.0.8`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\user0\Desktop\app\target\debug\build\bzip2-sys-faace576cdcf109f\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
  --- stdout
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-gnu")
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-gnu")
  CC_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu = None
  CC_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu = None
  HOST_CC = None
  CC = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu = None
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  CFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("true")
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  running: "gcc.exe" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "bzip2-1.0.8" "-D_WIN32" "-DBZ_EXPORT" "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64" "-DBZ_NO_STDIO" "-o" "C:\\Users\\user0\\Desktop\\app\\target\\debug\\build\\bzip2-sys-f1b348dca76e3f18\\out\\lib\\bzip2-1.0.8/blocksort.o" "-c" 
"bzip2-1.0.8/blocksort.c"
  cargo:warning=cc1.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
  exit code: 1

  --- stderr


  error occurred: Command "gcc.exe" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "bzip2-1.0.8" "-D_WIN32" "-DBZ_EXPORT" "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64" "-DBZ_NO_STDIO" "-o" "C:\\Users\\user0\\Desktop\\app\\target\\debug\\build\\bzip2-sys-f1b348dca76e3f18\\out\\lib\\bzip2-1.0.8/blocksort.o" "-c" "bzip2-1.0.8/blocksort.c" with args "gcc.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 1).
```

My Cargo.toml file:

```
[package]
name = "app"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
ggez = "*"
```

- [environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvNed.png)
- [MinGW options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h45XE.png)
- [MinGW folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E29WP.png)

Comment: I'd say that your MingGW is 32-bits only, but your target is 64-bits. Try compiling with `cargo build --target=i686-pc-windows-gnu`. Or installing a MinGW with 64-bits support, that should be the default for modern installations.

Comment: @rodrigo I reinstall MinGW and everything started to work well. If you wish, you can answer my question and I will mark the answer as correct

Comment: Sure, let me expand the text a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows-Gnu there are actually two different targets:

- `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` to build 64-bit executables and
- `i686-pc-windows-gnu` to build 32-bit ones.

When you use `cargo` you tell it what target to use with `--target`, but the default will be the one you are using, that usually will be the 64-bit one.

When invoking `gcc` the bitness of the target will result in the parameter `-m32` or `-m64`. Usually GCC will accept both options, but sometimes, if you have a 32-bit only version of the compiler, if you (or `cargo`) use the `-m64` option the compiler will complain with that:

```
sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
```

The right solution is to install a 64-bit MinGW version, that should be the default nowadays. I mean, the usual fork is now called [MinGW-**w64**](https://www.mingw-w64.org/).